# How to escape regular expression special characters in CoreNLP TokenRegex pattern?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

How to escape special characters (e.g.`$` or `?`) in CoreNLP TokenRegex pattern (e.g. `/$[0-9,]+/` where `$` refer to the currency symbol). For example, in java the pattern would be `\\$[0-9,]+` .

Is there a fuction similar to `Pattern.quote()` in CoreNLP TokenRegex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For special characters inside of regular expressions -- as in your example of `/$[0-9,]+/` -- this is the same escape character as Javan's Pattern. That is, '\'. So in your case, `/\$[0-9,]+/`.

For TokensRegex special characters, you can always quote them. For example: `foo "[" citation needed "]"`.